# Init routed component after fetching data in root component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I create quite simple angular app where all routed components use data which are fetched from API right after load of application. So i thought that the best way to start fetching will be in root component which stores also router outlet. And after this, activated routed component should fetch data from another address specific for this component. But it cannot do it without data fetched in root component. It also doesn't wait of course for complete first fetching so eventually all process ends with error.

And now my question is: How to force routed component to wait till start fetching in root component is complete? Maybe some way to pass information about it, by using some service or invoke it from root? Or any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use a cache instead of a root component.  When the active component requests data, populate the cache.  Then when the next component requests data, check first the cache, otherwise make the request.  You will need a way to bust the cache so your data doesn't become stale.

Angular has a [$cacheFactory](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$cacheFactory) (not sure what version of angular you are using) that can be fairly useful for a trivial cache system (including an LRU cache).